# After the Objective-C and Swift are mixed together, the size of IPA became larger

Tags: ios, swift

Our project is Objective-C. But after mixing with Swift, the IPA size changed a lot. Even if there are only a few Swift files, the package increases a lot and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It's not about mixing, Swift app IPA size is very much alone (A blank app IPA would also near 100 MB)

Comment: However, I want to keep the ipa size in the past. What should I do

Comment: Don't use Swift.

Answer (score 1):

See app size in app store, all updated apps are greater than 100MB, don't worry about that.

It's due to Apple new App Thining and Bitcode Impact introduced with iOS 9
Swift runtime libraries are copied into your application bundle and it is around 30MB alone.

If you create new app with swift and create IPA without anything, It would also very big in size (Check this on your system)

Check this link as well
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16339